# Regexp to get last occurance of ipv4 in a string with dots

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex to find ipv4 matches:

```
/(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/
```

I need to get last possible ipv4 occurance in the strings below:

```
abc 195.4.205.1 fgh
abc 4.195.4.205.1 fgh
abc 4.195.4.205.1.99 fgh
abc 4.195.4.205.1.999 fgh
```

Results for these strings should be:

```
195.4.205.1
195.4.205.1
4.205.1.99
4.205.1.99
```

I've read about **negative lookahead**, but I have no idea how to use it.

Please help me. Thank in advance

Comment: You could match the `# ` and then the ip pattern `.*# (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` https://regex101.com/r/6LcFOA/1

Comment: Sorry, there was my fault, I've edited task

Comment: What is this "abc" ..... "fgh"? and why did you pick "4.205.1.99" from the last two column where the string is "abc 4.195.4.205.1.999 fgh"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a lookaround. You can match until the end of the string, and then use a word boundary and backtrack until the last occurrence where the pattern matches without an end boundary to get the `99` in `999`

Use a single capture group to get the full part instead of separate groups, and use a non capture group for the alternations inside the outer group.

```
.*\b((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E9s5Ts/1)

Or a bit shorted with a quantifier to repeat 3 times:

```
.*\b((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})
```

```js
const regex = /.*\b((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})/;
[
  "abc 195.4.205.1 fgh",
  "abc 4.195.4.205.1 fgh",
  "abc 4.195.4.205.1.99 fgh",
  "abc 4.195.4.205.1.999 fgh"
].forEach(s => {
  const match = s.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]);
  }
});
```

If you want to match more numbers in a string, you could start the pattern by optionally matching digits followed by a dot, and then use your pattern in capture group 1.

```
(?:\d+\.)*((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SfM5rN/1)

```js
const regex = /(?:\d+\.)*((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})/g;
const s = " abc 4.195.4.205.1.999 fgh 23.59.10.662 juia abc 195.4.205.1 fgh abc 4.195.4.205.1 fgh abc 4.195.4.205.1.99 fghabc 4.195.4.205.1.999 fgh";
console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```

Comment: thank you very much for the example. I would be very grateful if you could show a regex so that it works for several ipv4 in one line. For example: abc 4.195.4.205.1.999 fgh 23.59.10.662 juia ... [expected results: 4.205.1.99; 23.59.10.66 ...]
In other words, I need to make regex work if all strings are in one line.

Comment: @xivij I have added an update at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: it works for PHP (Group1 result) but doesn't work for Javascript :(

Comment: @xivij Did you run the Javascript examples in the code? You can see the group1 values.